# Persistent background processes in Ubuntu for Windows?

Tags: windows

I'm using Ubuntu in the Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10. From what I can tell, this environment cleans up after itself when the last terminal window is closed: background processes (e.g. ssh-agent) are shut down, and new shells will show a new `/init` process at PID 1 with a new start time.

**Is there a way to extend the life of this environment**, other than keeping one terminal open all the time?

According to the Microsoft Store, this is the 20170830.1 build of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Thank you! Looks like this will be a feature of future releases of Windows (currently available in Windows Insiders Build 17046).